# If Cell contains specific text in col A copy cell from Col C into Col F stacked

Tags: excel, vba, copy, cell

I am working on code where if in Column "A"="test" then to copy cell from Col C into Col F but without spaces .
Can someone please help?

```
Sub FindValuePaste()

    Dim FndRng As Range
    Dim cll As Range

    Set FndRng = Range("A3:A9")

    For Each cll In FndRng
        If cll.Value = "test" Then
           ' cll.Offset(0, 5) = cll.Offset(0, 2).Value
            Range("F1").Offset(1) = cll.Offset(0, 2).Value
        End If
    Next cll

End sub
```

Appreciate your help and thank you in advance!

[image: Excel view in below screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `.End(xlUp).Row` to locate the last row

```vb
Sub FindValuePaste()
    Dim FndRng As Range
    Dim cll As Range
    Dim lastRow as Long, oSht as Worksheet
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet ' modify as needed
    lastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row 
    If len(oSht.Range("F" & lastRow)) > 0 Then  lastRow = lastRow + 1
    Set FndRng = oSht.Range("A3:A9")

    For Each cll In FndRng
        If cll.Value = "test" Then
           ' cll.Offset(0, 5) = cll.Offset(0, 2).Value
            oSht.Range("F" & lastRow).Value = cll.Offset(0, 2).Value
            lastRow = lastRow + 1            
        End If
    Next cll
End sub
```

---

- Use `CountA` to get the count of non-blank cells (The data should be start from F1 on Col F)

```vb
Sub FindValuePaste2()

    Dim FndRng As Range
    Dim cll As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet ' modify as needed
    lastRow = Application.CountA(oSht.Columns("F")) + 1
    Set FndRng = oSht.Range("A3:A9")
    For Each cll In FndRng
        If cll.Value = "test" Then
           ' cll.Offset(0, 5) = cll.Offset(0, 2).Value
            oSht.Range("F" & lastRow) = cll.Offset(0, 2).Value
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        End If
    Next cll

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Matching Row From Another Column

[image]

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Sub FindValuePaste()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("A3:A9")
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = ws.Range("F3")
    
    Dim scell As Range
    
    For Each scell In srg.Cells
        If StrComp(CStr(scell.Value), "test", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            dcell.Value = scell.Offset(, 2).Value
            Set dcell = dcell.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next scell
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a formula in cell F3:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(FILTER(A3:C9,A3:A9="test"),0,3)," ","")
```

- Where the FILTER function filters the table A3:C9 to only rows with 'test'
- Where the INDEX function picks column number 3 from that filtered range
- Where SUBSTITUTE replaces the spaces (although I did not see the necessity in the example sheet)